# Showing no output

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

So I was trying to count the total number of negative numbers in the stack and I wrote this code but something went wrong with it and its showing no output. I am a beginner in c++ so I am sure it will be quite wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

size_t i(stack<int> s){
    int count=0;

    while(s.size() !=0){

        if(s.top()<0){
            count++;
            s.pop();

        }       else if(s.top()>0){
            s.pop();
        }       else{}

        cout<<count<<endl;
    }
    return count;
}
int main(){

    stack<int> s;

    s.push(-1);
    s.push(2);
    s.push(-2);

    size_t i(stack<int> s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe because it doesn't even *compile*. `s()` isn't even valid. `std::stack` has no call- `operator ()` Try `!s.empty()`

Comment: oh yeah sorry i forgot to write it in here.

Comment: Great. now, if you think `size_t i(stack<int> s);` in `main()` actually *executes* the `i()` function, you're mistaken. It doesn't. It *declares* a function. You want simply `i(s);`

Comment: I don't see any calls to create any output. Try `std::cout << i(s) << std::endl;`.

Comment: @RSahu its in the `i()` function itself. Took me a minute to see it too.

Comment: its giving an output but its still wrong. It should give 2 as output.

Comment: In your `main()` function you do not call `i()` you simply redeclare it.

Comment: @user4032883 its giving *exactly* the output you asked it to. With each iteration, regardless of whether the popped element is negative or not, you print the *running* total. -2 means 1, 2 means still 1, and -1 means 2, thus your output is 1 1 2. If you want just the total lose the `cout <<...` in `i()` completely and put `std::cout << i(s) << std::endl;` in `main()` as R.Sahu suggested.

Comment: `size_t i(stack<int> s);` does not call a function it declares a function. Please learn some of the basics of C++.

Comment: I will Captain Obvlious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `main()` function you do not call `i()` you simply redeclare it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

size_t i(stack<int> s){
    int count=0;

    while(s.size() !=0){

        if(s.top()<0){
            count++;
            s.pop();

        }       else if(s.top()>0){
            s.pop();
        }       else{}

        cout<<count<<endl;
    }
    return count;
}
int main(){

    stack<int> s;

    s.push(-1);
    s.push(2);
    s.push(-2);

    size_t i(stack<int> s); // this DOES NOT call the function

    i(s); // <== THIS calls the function!!!

    return 0;
}
```

Your statement `size_t i(stack<int> s);` does not call the function, it simply tells the compiler what parameters it accepts and what its return type is.